# Exclude characters in awk while calculating mininum

Tags: awk

Below is the dataset I have

```
10.25 3.5
10.15 4.5
# value1 
10.25 3.5
12.15 4.5
11.25 3.5
10.05 4.5
```

I tried to find the minium of column1 with

```
awk 'NF' FILENAME |sort -k1 - | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'
```

but I endup with

```
#
```

as the result. I have also tried with -F"|#"..but the result is the same.
My expected out is the min value of column1

```
10.05
```

I have data files with columns numerical and special characters. I would now wish to ger Min from each file

Desired output

```
10.05(from file1)
 9.02 (from file2)

 ..... (from n files)
```

My question is how to ignore rows with such characters and get All min values from each file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this awk:

```
awk 'FNR==1 {
   if (min != "")
      print min, "(from", fn ")"
   min = ""
   fn = FILENAME
}
$1+0 == $1 && (min=="" || $1 < min) {
   min=$1
}
END {
   print min, "(from", fn ")"
}' *.txt
```

```
10.05 (from file1.txt)
9.02 (from file2.txt)
```

- `$1+0 == $1` check is to ensure `$1` is a numeric field
- `(min=="" || $1 < min)`: sets `min=$1` if `min` is unset or if `$1 < min`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '($1+0) == $1{print $1, "(from " FILENAME ")"}' file* | sort -k2 -k1,1n | uniq -f1
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file1
10.25 3.5
10.15 4.5
# value1
10.25 3.5
12.15 4.5
11.25 3.5
10.05 4.5

$ cat file2
10.25 3.5
10.15 4.5
# value1
10.25 3.5
12.15 4.5
11.25 3.5
10.05 4.5

$ cat file3
10.25 3.5
10.15 4.5
# value1
10.25 3.5
12.15 4.5
11.25 3.5
10.05 4.5
```

.

```
$ awk '($1+0) == $1{print $1, "(from " FILENAME ")"}' file{1..3}
10.25 (from file1)
10.15 (from file1)
10.25 (from file1)
12.15 (from file1)
11.25 (from file1)
10.05 (from file1)
10.25 (from file2)
10.15 (from file2)
10.25 (from file2)
12.15 (from file2)
11.25 (from file2)
10.05 (from file2)
10.25 (from file3)
10.15 (from file3)
10.25 (from file3)
12.15 (from file3)
11.25 (from file3)
10.05 (from file3)
```

.

```
$ awk '($1+0) == $1{print $1, "(from " FILENAME ")"}' file{1..3} | sort -k2 -k1,1n
10.05 (from file1)
10.15 (from file1)
10.25 (from file1)
10.25 (from file1)
11.25 (from file1)
12.15 (from file1)
10.05 (from file2)
10.15 (from file2)
10.25 (from file2)
10.25 (from file2)
11.25 (from file2)
12.15 (from file2)
10.05 (from file3)
10.15 (from file3)
10.25 (from file3)
10.25 (from file3)
11.25 (from file3)
12.15 (from file3)
```

.

```
$ awk '($1+0) == $1{print $1, "(from " FILENAME ")"}' file{1..3} | sort -k2 -k1,1n | uniq -f1
10.05 (from file1)
10.05 (from file2)
10.05 (from file3)
```

Comment: One of those rare occasions where Ed has used anything outside `awk` to get the job done :)

Comment: Well, I figured you already had the all-awk option covered :-).